# How do I format a floated div to contain statically positioned elements?

Tags: html, css, debugging, layout

It is possible that this problem doesn't display on your computer. A working example (what I want) can be seen at http://ethoma.com/wp/?p=1 . And the bug can probably be seen at http://ethoma.com/wp/ .  If you can't see the problem, basically the tertiary column is displaying to the left of the content, colliding with the aside column (first column). I have a float:left aside column and inside there is a statically positioned div so the twitter feed and logo follow you down the page.

Notice that the aside doesn't envelop its content. How do I correct this? thank you for all responses.

Comment: You can't just change the html and the order of elements, and expect you CSS to still work. Please try changing your CSS first, before asking us to fix your problem.

Comment: I don't seem to see what you are saying. The only change that I made was to use position:static. I don't believe I made any html changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guide make everything inside the article relative, float left, set equal widths, declare heights and text-align as you wish.